# Как вывести поверх одного Activity другое, чтоб на заднем плане было размыто первое?

Tags: android, java

Как вывести поверх одного Activity другое, чтоб на заднем плане было размыто первое?
Использую следующий код взятый из сэмплов, но в результате выполнения вызываемое активити закрывает предыдущее полностью(не видно вызывающего):

```
public class BetweenRoundActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

В отличие от семпла, к Активити из которого вызывается BetweenRoundActivity и к BetweenRoundActivity применена тема Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.

Вызываю следующим кодом(по нажатию кнопки):

```
private OnClickListener mButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(GameActivity.this,  
                                 BetweenRoundActivity.class));
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сделать Activity прозрачной:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTransparent">
 ... 
</activity>
```

Задекларировать MyTransparent можно примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>   
   <style name="Theme.MyTransparent" parent="android:Theme">     
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>     
      <item name="android:windowBackground">#00000000</item>     
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>     
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>     
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>     
      <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>   
   </style> 
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для `BetweenRoundActivity` в манифесте поставьте `style/Theme.Dialog`

```
<activity
   android:name=".BetweenRoundActivity "
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

тем самым `BetweenRoundActivity` откроется диалогом поверх `GameActivity`, которое будет размыто.