# установить прозрачность для активити, чтобы было видно нижнее активити

Tags: java, android, xml

есть два активити , одно открывается сверху другого и на нём gridview, хочу чтобы верхнее было полупрозрачным (не полностью прозрачное, не android:style/Theme.Translucent) , как загрузить фоновую картинку я понял android:background="@drawable/picture" .  И вот везде на вопрос как сделать его прозрачным, говорят поставить android:alpha="0.5" , ну и что ? получается просто СВетлая картинка, но не прозрачная , через неё не видно элементов нижнего активити.. Еще говорят установить color ARGB , где A отвечает за прозрачность, но получается такая же Светлая картинка, не прозрачная..

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:textFilterEnabled="false"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/vvv"
    android:alpha="0.5">
</GridView>
```

В манифесте я даже не знаю  , что еще пробовать , пока вот 
    введите  
     сюда код

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73603/Как-вывести-поверх-одного-activity-другое-чтоб-на-заднем-плане-было-размыто-пер

Answer (score 4):

Для реализации того что хотите лучше использовать фрагменты (либо другие варианты, `PopupWindow` например).

---

UPD. А действительно, Вы правы. Добавил стиль:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

В `colors.xml`

`<color name="transparent">#55000000</color>`
В таком случае получился результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно и `android:alpha="0.5"` в разметку добавить.

Но по жизненному циклу не вызвался `onStop` у первой `Activity`. Логи:

```
E/onPause: onPause
E/onCreate2: onCreate2
E/onResume2: onResume2
```

При повороте экрана:

```
E/onPause2: onPause2
E/onStop2: onStop2
E/onDestroy2: onDestroy2
E/onCreate2: onCreate2
E/onResume2: onResume2
E/onStop: onStop
E/onDestroy: onDestroy
E/onCreate: onCreate
E/onResume: onResume
E/onPause: onPause
```

Comment: Но как же так ? стоит поставить android:style/Theme.Translucent и из этого активити я вижу, то которое лежит ниже(с жизненным циклом STOP или Pause) но  я хочу не на 100 процентов прозрачное .. Но всё же даже исходя из многочисленных тем , о том , как с одного активити видеть нижележащее (лежащее ниже в таске) , можно сделать вывод , что это как то делается. Да и то что я могу сделать окно на 100 проц прозрачным говорит , о том , что можно сделать и на 50 проц прозрачным.  И еще я не понимаю почему все говорят что, если поставить  android:alpha="0.5" , то окно будет прозрачным..хотя это не так

Comment: @Turalllb, хм, интересно, ушел копаться.

Comment: @Turalllb, и что активити на заднем фоне будет видно и после поворота экрана?.. Вот очень сомневаюсь, ведь его в таком случае надо пересоздать, а активити, с которого ушли пересоздаваться не будет.

Comment: не нужно пересоздавать нижний активити. нижний вообще не трогается.  верхнее активити , которое создается вот                    <activity
            android:name=".MEM"
            android:label="@string/MEM"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    </activity>  И можете хоть переворачивать экран, это активити не имеет вообще фона, оно прозрачно. надо прописать это в манифесте .

Comment: @Turalllb, как говорится, век живи, век учись. Спасибо за хороший вопрос, надо почитать в чем тонкости.

Comment: И вам спасибо за скорый ответ. Но у меня пока, что не получилось.  В colors.xml
создаю
<color name="xxx">#55000000</color>   В стиле применяю этот цвет <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/xxx</item> но в логе ошибка Error:(17, 47) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '@android:color/xxx').

Comment: @Turalllb не `@android:color`, a `@color/xxx`

Comment: я понял. я правил @android:color который находится в Sdk. создал свой colors.xml в values и добавил туда цвет #55000000.  Стиль созданный применил к GridView , который у меня на активити . даже добавил android:alpha="0.5"  . Результат отрицательный. нижнее активити не виднооо(   alpha="0.5 делает фон просто светлее . В многих местах написано , что в цвете #55000000 первые две цифры это прозрачность. Но что , что не выходит..

Comment: @Turalllb в манифесте для `activity` пропишите `<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"/>`

Comment: Да я додумался до того, что не gridview должен быть прозрачен , а сам активити, но увы прописал в манифесте и тот же результат. но вот только , что пришла мысль , что если даже активити прозрачен , то его прикрывает не прозрачный gridview. сейчас попробую убрать gridview или уменьшить.

Comment: Не вышло. я даже создал новый проект . всё проделал. никак. изза альфа 0.5 я получаю более светлый верхний , активити через который нижний не видно.

Comment: УРА!!!  я смог . ошибка была в том , что вместо android:theme="@style/AppTheme.youTransparent" > я писал style="@style/AppTheme.youTransparent". ФУХ, можно спокойно ложиться спать) Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: VAndrJ, вот для вас интересная статья по теме  https://habrahabr.ru/post/215077/ . Описаны способы не просто делать прозрачное окно , а еще и размывать. Раньше был    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND , но этот способ больше не работает в новых апи.